# How to install Octave 3.8 with Java on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, octave, downgrade

I currently have Octave 4.2 with Java (installed view Homebrew) on Mac (OS 10.12.6). How can I downgrade to Octave 3.8?

I tried the generic instructions in this thread, but they did not help: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)  There's just one Octave and no versions.

I am not wedded to using Homebrew for this.  I'll explore any way of getting Octave 3.8.

Comment: You may need to resort to using MacPorts to install Octave 3.8+ - especiall with Java support.  I believe it still has those old formulas available.  BTW, I'm not sure what your motivation is to downgrade as Octave 3.8 and lower is considered quite old.

Comment: Thanks reyreng, I'll check that out. I inherited some legacy octave code that is failing on the java calls. ("java_new" not defined, etc). I think it will be easier to get the old version of octave working than to update the code.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.  OK, good luck!

Comment: I never used java in GNU Octave but after reading NEWS and a quick search in hg: "java_new is obsolete and will be removed from a future version of Octave; please use javaObject instead" So after all I think it should be easier to adapt the old code to Octave 4.2

Comment: Interesting, thanks Andy. If its really just a simple name change, that would be easier than I thought. octave 3.8 via `port install octave-legacy +java` is still compiling after 4 hours!)

Comment: Btw, `java_new` was deprecated in 4.0 so you don't have to go to 3.8. My strategy to convert your code for 4.2 would be to install 4.0, then run your code and fix all the warnings because deprecated functions, then go to 4.2